# Windows service timeout at start without internet connection

Tags: c#, windows, service

I wrote a service in C# that performs a bunch of requests to my server in timers.
If the internet connection is ok at boot or at the time I start it manually everything works just fine.
However, if the connection is not given and the service tries to start, it times out.

I am not a pro regarding Windows services. I tried to fix this by delaying the start type (automatic delyayed) but it does not work either.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: When I've had this in the past it's due to Windows trying to check certificate revocation lists for TLS certificates and/or code-signing. Try following the steps documented here to disable these checks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc753863(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: why dont you check if internet or your service/server etc. is available and if it is, you perform whatever you need to do, if its not available then you handle it ... there are different ways to do so form retrying to just terminating the service etc.

Comment: Are you trying to connect in `OnStart()`?

Comment: Don't delay the service's start. The only reasonable way forward is to delay the service's operation. Don't just try to do everything during service startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who gave me input on this matter. I delayed the actions of the service in the OnStart function and I additionally disable the logic of the service until the internet connection is established. I do not have a problem since